# can a webpage on a mobile browser ask/get users location from the phone?

Tags: iphone, android, browser, html

Is there any way that a webpage can make a request for the users location from the android / iphone device ?

Since all I need is the users location, I am trying to figure out if there is anyway I can bypass developing a **native app** and use some nifty html5 call to just get the users location so all a user would need to do is visit my webpage and provide permission to access his/her location?

Comment: you can ask in javascript, but most browsers by default will then ask the user for explicit consent. Try clickin the dot above the little orange streetview dude in google maps in Firefox/iPad/newer browsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Webkit browsers on Android and Iphone support geolocation. The Google maps api has some great [info](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#DetectingUserLocation) on it.

Comment: Have you seen a quick and dirty sample for doing that with the Google maps api?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Google Maps API (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/introduction.html), particularly the sensor parameter...may give you want you need.